# Wirelss Signal distribution

Tags: matlab, signal-processing, wireless

I am struggling to model a wireless signal with some PDFs distribution. The problem is I am working on an older version of matlab which doesn't carry these functions, such as; `normpdf`, `chi1pdf` and `raylpdf`.

Any kind of help would be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Your question is unclear. Where are you stuck exactly? Do you have a model in mind, and you're struggling with implementing it?

Comment: I cannot model the signal as Rayleigh distributed signal.

Comment: This doesn't answer my question.

Comment: Yes I have a model in Mind. But I thought that there is a function that does it.

Comment: In that case, it would be helpful if you give a short description of your model... don't you think?

Comment: I have a receiver, with blind detection, this receiver tries to detect signals. I need to generate signal that is not continuous. am looking for some sort of discontinuity of the signal. that is to say, the signal in some intervals is on and off in the others.

Comment: Add this to the question please.

Answer (score 0):

#### Generate any pdf from analytical expression

If you have a random number generator following the normal distribution, you can use the [Inverse transform sampling](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_transform_sampling) to generate random numbers of any distribution.

#### Generate any pdf from empirical data

```
inputData = ...

% Statistics
pdf = hist(inputData,ceil(sqrt(numel(inputData))));
pdf_norm = pdf/sum(pdf);
cdf_norm = cumsum(pdf_norm);

% Plot
figure
subplot(1,2,1)
title('pdf (normalized)')
bar(pdf_norm); 
subplot(1,2,2)
title('cdf (normalized)')
plot(cdf_norm,'r')
hold off
```

Comment: I only have one source of signal.

Comment: So? In case I may have understood wrongly your text, could you please indicate clearly which is exactly your problem?

Comment: How can I model the source signal, so its discontinuous signal.